# Is there any way to loop audio smoothly with mpv?

Tags: audio, mpv

I am effectively looking to play audio and when it loops (because I used the `--loop` flag) I want it to not have a delay afterwards.

I would appreciate some help on this.

edit: I read the man page but it's quite long and I didn't really get much for it I mostly focused on the low latency section not sure if that's correct

Since my question is unclear:

When I play some audio on mpv:
`mpv --loop path/to/audio.opus`

However, when the audio loops there is a short delay. What I want is to make that delay as small as possible. My question is, how can I reduce this delay?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you certain the delay is not result of the audio file ending with a few seconds of silence?

Comment: Let me quickly check. edit: There doesn't seem to be any silence as far as I can tell although I don't really know how to check properly.

Comment: I can' verify there is no silence but the song name is "Rouxls Kaard" from the deltarune ost

Comment: Consumer media players are not always good at playing files gaplessly, even if there is no technical gap. Also, consumer audio formats sometimes put arbitrary short sections of silence beginning & end. If you open these in a 'proper' audio editor, they will often strip these few samples again, so you can't tell it was in the file. All you can really do is drop two copies of the audio on something like Audacity, drag one to the end of the other & then play across the join. Apple's iTunes used to have a flag for gapless playback… but it was removed some years ago.

Comment: For more context I am using a thinkpad l14 gen 1. Do you know if there are any issues with this? I see what you mean though. Not sure if those things apply to me as when I run mpv wait for it to load pause it go back to the begining and hit play it plays sound instantly and this track very abruptly stops  don't think gaps were added or anything like that at least. I was just wondering what can I actually do to reduce the gap.

Comment: The computer & OS are actually irrelevant to this, the player, the file format & whether it's internally padded need examining, or eliminating by using a non-consumer format, aif or wav, which wil never be padded. Manually queueing the track in a media player is really just guesswork; that won't tell you anything.

Comment: The player I am using is `mpv`, the file format is `.opus` but I will convert the file to a `.wav` file and see if it loops properly.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have converted it to .wav file using ffmpeg but after inspecting it in audacity it seems that it has some gap at the end. After having trimmed away the silence, in mpv there is still the same delay as before.

Comment: If it's still doing it in mpv from wav, then it's likely to be the player itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the JACK backend as well as Pulse, and audio loops fine for me.

I think the problem is with the file itself. Opus has discretely sized frames, so if the encoded audio is not exactly a multiple of the frame size, the last frame will be padded with silence. Check the file in Audacity (Audacity can loop too), trim it if necessary, and try exporting it as WAV and try playing that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).